# How to use agg function while not drop other columns in dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

Suppose I have a dataframe like below:

```
+-------------+----------+-----+------+
| key         | Time     |value|value2|
+-------------+----------+-----+------+
|  1          |        1 |  1  |   1  |
|  1          |        2 |  2  |   2  |
|  1          |        4 |  3  |   3  |
|  2          |        2 |  4  |   4  |
|  2          |        3 |  5  |   5  | 
+-------------+----------+-----+------+
```

I want to select the key with same value with the least time. For this case, the is the dataframe I want.

```
+----------+----------+-----+------+
| Time     | key      |value|value2|
+----------+----------+-----+------+
|  1       |        1 |  1  |   1  |
|  2       |        2 |  4  |   4  |
+----------+----------+-----+------+
```

I tried use `groupBy` and `agg`, but these operations will drop the `value` columns. Is there a way to keep the `value1` and `value2` columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `struct` to create a tuple containing the `time` column and everything you want to keep (the `s` column in the code below). Then, you can use `s.*` to unfold the struct and retrieve your columns.

```scala
val result = df
    .withColumn("s", struct('Time, 'value, 'value2))
    .groupBy("key")
    .agg(min('s) as "s")
    .select("key", "s.*")

// to order the columns the way you want:
val new_result = result.select("Time", "key", "value", "value2")
// or
val new_result = result.select("Time", df.columns.filter(_ != "time") : _*)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but what if the order of columns I want is time, key, value1, value2? I've edited the dataframe I want in the question.

Comment: I updated the answer, you can simply achieve that with an additional `select`.